# Reference for a result in toric geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, toric-geometry

I want to know where I can find the proof of the following theorem : if $X$ is a smooth toric variety, then $H^{\bullet}(X) \cong CH^{\bullet}(X)$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you clarify what is $CH^*$? Also, what exactly cohomology groups are you considering? For projective varieties there are many choices.

Comment: @MoisheCohen : thanks for your comment ! $CH^*$ is the Chow ring and $H^*$ is the cohomology ring (de Rham, singular) which should all coincide in this nice case. I think I probably forgot to put projective in the hypothesis as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Section 5.2 of Fulton there is a theorem that says that for $X$ a smooth complete toric variety, $CH_*X \cong H_*X$, *freely* generated by the orbit closures.

Your statement follows by Poincare duality and universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Ok, this is great. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question : are Grassmanians toric varieties ? Because their cohomology rings seems similar.

Comment: Not stupid at all. No, Grassmannians are usually not toric. (For example, one can prove that the only smooth toric varieties of Picard number 1 are the projective spaces.) However, Grassmannians do belong to a wider class called _cellular varieites_, and these also have the property you asked about. Feel free to ask more questions if you want details.

Comment: I will surely have more questions but probably later since I have soon an exam about toric varieties and this was by curiosity. Thanks again for the explanations !

Comment: Dear @Nefertiti, can I ask you about more informations about cellular varieties ? More precisely, I know that with Grothendieck ring allows us to compute the cohomology of smooth projective varieties which are polynomials in $L := [\mathbb A^1]$. Is this related to the definition of cellular varieties ? Where can I find information about it ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @rain: my earlier comment may have been a bit misleading --- I really know nothing about cellular varieties. If you google "cellular variety" you will quickly learn everything I know on the topic, and more. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find anything online (except some articles which looks a bit technical for me). Do you know a document which defines cellular varieties and give some examples ? Thanks again !